# Reg ex returning extra match

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to pick the text between item 3 to item 4a, if it is not able to find the item 4a then it should look for the item 5 to end the search.

Below reg ex(with group) is able to pick the correct values. However, it returns a tuple with the matched groups.

```
re.findall(r'item 3\D(.*?)(item 4a|item 5)',"item 3 first value item 4 foo item 4a and item 5 item 3 second value item 4a")
```

Output:

```
[('first value item 4 foo ', 'item 4a'), ('second value ', 'item 4a')]
```

Please suggest any better method to achieve this without using group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `non-capturing group` with:

```
re.findall(r'item 3\D(.*?)(?:item 4a|item 5)',"item 3 first value item 4 foo item 4a and item 5 item 3 second value item 4a")
```

Comment: Thanks @zipa .. exactly what i needed !

Answer (score 0):

You can use *look ahead (?=)* or make the second group non-captured `(?:`, so the `item4a` or `item5` will not be returned:

```
re.findall(r'item 3\D(.*?)(?=item 4a|item 5)',"item 3 first value item 4 foo item 4a and item 5 item 3 second value item 4a")
​#                          ^^   # or use ?: as the other answer
# ['first value item 4 foo ', 'second value ']
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to respond ..appreciate your help.